# Quasiconcavity of a particular function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have to numerically maximize, for $x\in (0,0.5)$, the following function for several different values of parameters $a>0$ and $b>0$:
\begin{equation}
f_{a,b}(x) = a\big(\log x + \log(1-x)\big) + b \log\Big(\dfrac{2\text{tanh}^{-1}(1-2x)}{1-2x}\Big)
\end{equation}
I would like to know if my numerical optimization recovers a global maximum, so I would like to know for which values of $a$ and $b$ the function is quasiconcave.

I have plotted the function for different values of $a$ and $b$ and quasiconcavity seems to hold, but I have not been able to prove it. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: The concavity does not hold for e.g. $b=3$ and $a=1$

Comment: That's what I meant by it only appears to hold for some values of $a$ and $b$, I will make this clearer in the question, thank you.

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted your question :)

Comment: I further edited the question and changed the domain to $(0,0.5)$ from $(0,1)$ as the function is symmetric around $0.5$. This seems to eliminate the non-quasiconcavity issues I had when plotting the function for some values of $a$ and $b$.